# Getters and Setters - proper convention

Tags: java

I've been told the following code does not follow correct getters and setters convention. I'm struggling to see why or where. I'm using the constructor to pass a new team name to the set method. Am a beginner at Java but I thought both getter and setter methods seemed fine. Am I wrong? Thanks.

```
public class Team {

  private String teamName;

  public Team(String newName) {
    setName(newName);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return teamName;
  }

  public void setName(String newName) {
    teamName = newName;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return teamName;
  }

  public boolean equals(Team t){
    if(t.getName().equals(teamName)){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }       
  }

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but the correct signature of `equals()` takes an `Object` argument. Also once `equals()` is implemented, `hashCode()` should be implemented as well...

Comment: Talking about proper conventions, the name of the original field would look better as `name`. Using "team" in the name of the member is redundant.

Comment: Also: `return t.getName().equals(teamName);` is a shorter version of the same `equals()` code.

Answer (score 7):

If the variable name is `X`, then the getter/setter would be `getX/setX`.

Any good IDE, like IntelliJ, will generate these for you.

It'll also generate equals for you properly, which you did not, and give you a hashCode.  You always need to implement those two together.  Read Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" [chapter 3](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/project_old/Chapter3.pdf) to see the hows and whys.

Comment: Unless the datatype is `boolean`, where the convention can be either `getX/setX` or `isX/setX`.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `getTeamName` and `setTeamName` instead. Generally, if your property is called `foo`, the getter and setter would be `getFoo` and `setFoo`, respectively.

Of course you can also just refactor the property name from `teamName` to `name`, since your class is already called `Team`, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I disagree, ``getTeamName``/``setTeamName`` is redundant, you know it's a team, why write Team again in your code if you already know it is a team? ``getName``/``setName`` seems perfectly valid and preferable IMHO, especially if you're going to use interfaces. Thus I believe he should rename his variable to ``name``, IMO.

Comment: @miguel.martin Seeing that the OP was asking about proper convention, Joao Silva's answer is right on the money. Whether you disagree with convention is a different matter altogether.

Comment: @nickecarlo Renaming the variable ``teamName`` to ``name`` will also make his code have proper convention, but with less redundancy. (and less changing code)

Comment: @miguel.martin I agree. But that's not part of the question.

Comment: I think miguel is right - better to give the correct answer, and explain why, rather than stick to the narrow confines of the question.

Comment: Conceptually, it is the getter/setter pair that names the property, and the instance variable is an implementation detail only. It doesn't even have to exist. But, this is where a convention steps in and *recommends* same-named instance variable, in order to make the implementation code more readable and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below link for naming convention

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html

Also, [PDF Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf)

Section 8.8 "Capitalization of inferred names" and how names of properties should be.

Answer (score 0):

The getters and setters should refers to the attribute name.

The correct convention must be `getTeamName` and `setTeamName` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

for a variable named `teamName` your setter is called `setTeamName`.

Also do not use setter and getter methods in the constructor, because the setter could be overwritten by extending classes. In this way you could change the behavior of the constructor by only changing the setter and not the constructor. This should be avoided. So in the constructor you should use

```
public Team(String newName) {
  teamName = newName;
}
```